# When I run the program and click on my_rect nothing happens and eventualy it stops working

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            is_inside = my_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            print is_inside
            if is_inside == 1:
                myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)

                label = myfont.render("The Penrose Triangle by Roman Formicola", 5, (black))
                gameDisplay.blit(label, (300,150))
```

I had it my goal is that once you click on my_rect the message will stay there indefinately

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable holding your [`Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) (actually using the `Rect` class):

```
my_rect = pygame.Rect(400, 300, 100, 100)
```

Then you can use the [`collidepoint()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) method of `Rect` to check if the mouse position is inside `my_rect`:

```
...
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        is_inside = my_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, cyan, my_rect, 0)
...
```